# Can I run a Node app in the official Node docker image, or do I need to create my own registry containing the node-based app?

Tags: node.js, docker, dokku, jelastic

I've been looking into Docker for an easy way to scale an app. It's an React and Node app with ArangoDB database. I figured the best way to launch Arango was in a Docker and perhaps put the app and back-end in their own Docker images. However, realizing that this might require making my own private Docker registery makes adds an extra step that might be a little too much.

I liked the GUI of Jelastic, but if a Docker registry is really necessary I may go back to my Dokkku solution.

I don't suppose there is a way to use the official Node Docker image and then `git clone` my private repo into that?

Comment: I'm not %100 sure if the official docker images are safe to use in a production environment, but at least I would't utilize them on front facing containers. just because they are same configuration and available to everyone. so everyone -including hackers- aware of default configuration.

Comment: You do not have to place images on any registry. You can just use a dockerfile to locally build whatever image you wan't from the official node docker image. (Like tell in the docker file that you want the node image, and then that you would like to clone in your git repo.) You could also use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Comment: probably use docker compose - however you can build your app on top of a wildly use `node docker` image

Answer (score 2):

If you suddenly decide to use the private registry - in Jelastic Cloud you can set up your own Docker private registry, build custom docker images, pull created images into the custom registry and then deploy Docker containers.

All the necessary information and steps you can find in the docs below:

- [How to setup Docker private registry inside Jelastic.](https://docs.jelastic.com/docker-private-registry)
- [Example: How to build docker image in Jelastic](https://docs.jelastic.com/building-docker)
- [How to deploy docker containers from custom docker registry](https://docs.jelastic.com/docker-custom-registry)

Answer (score 0):

> However, realizing that this might require making my own private Docker registery makes adds an extra step that might be a little too much.

This is not correct. You do not need to run your own registry in order to use a custom Docker image; you can place that image on any existing public (or private) registry such as the ones operated by Docker ([Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/)) or CoreOS ([Quay](https://quay.io/))

If that is your only concern, I would suggest that using your own custom image on one of those hosted registry services (free or paid, public or private, as your needs require) would be one of the easiest options for you.